# list expand on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I can't seem to find any information that shows me how to expand a list. I would like it to be a horizontal type nav menu with each list having an image and when you click on the image it expands the "span" text. I hope this makes sense and that I didn't overlook someone else's thread with the same issue.

Example:

```
<ul id="Topics">
    <li class="Items">
        <img src="results.png" alt="Results">
        <span>Title here</span>
        <span>Some more text here</span>
    </li>
    <li class="Items">
        <img src="language.png" alt="Language here">
        <span>Title here</span>
        <span>Some more text here</span>
    </li>
    <li class="Items">
        <img src="wording.png" alt="Wording here">
        <span>Title here</span>
        <span>Some more text here</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: There are a bazillion examples of this to be found. Are you familiar with your browser's document inspector? You should know how to examine existing pages to see how they're built. CSS dropdown menus are the chicken nuggets of the web.

Comment: No problem, but I'm not sure how that's relevant. Your document inspector is one of the most valuable tools available. As a hobbyist, you want to be able to see what others have done so you aren't re-inventing the wheel. That's how you do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a rather fancy example:

```css
ul {
  text-align: left;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px 4px 17px 0;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
ul li {
  font: bold 12px/18px sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
ul li:hover {
  background: #555;
  color: #fff;
}
ul li ul {
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 48px;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
ul li ul li { 
  background: #555; 
  display: block; 
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
}
ul li ul li:hover { background: #666; }
ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<ul id="Topics">
 <li class="Items">
    Title here
    <ul>
      <li>some more text here</li>
      <li>some more text here</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="Items">
    Title here
    <ul>
      <li>some more text here</li>
      <li>some more text here</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="Items">
    Title here
    <ul>
      <li>some more text here</li>
      <li>some more text here</li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

The key code here is this part:

```
ul li:hover ul{
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Basically, we are selecting the nested `ul` inside of a hovered `li`. This works because the `:hover` psudo-class combined with the `ul` descendant makes sure that we are selecting this list only when its parent `li` is hovered.

Comment: I didn't use the image because it wasn't showing, but you can accomplish what you want within this setup. Just add the image in the list and style it with CSS. Experimentation is key.